# Aligning equation pairs at equivalence sign

Tags: align

How do I align the following so all the `\Leftrightarrows` are aligned under each other like so:

[image: What I want]

So far I have the following

```
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f_A (x)}{\partial x_1} & = w_1 - \lambda \alpha x_1^{\alpha -1} x_2^{1- \alpha} 
\Leftrightarrow
w_1 = \lambda \alpha x_1^{\alpha -1} x_2^{1- \alpha} 
\\[0.7em]
\frac{\partial f_A (x)}{\partial x_2} & = w_2 - \lambda x_1^\alpha (1- \alpha) x_2^{- \alpha} 
\Leftrightarrow
w_2 = \lambda x_1^\alpha (1-\alpha)x_2^{-\alpha}
\\[0.7em]
\frac{\partial f_A (x)}{\partial \lambda} & =x_1^\alpha x_2^{1-\alpha} - y 
\Leftrightarrow
y = x_1^\alpha x_2^{1-\alpha} 
\end{align}
```

Answer (score 4):

Set/formatted as three vertically aligned equation systems:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f_A (x)}{\partial x_1} & = w_1 - \lambda \alpha x_1^{\alpha
-1} x_2^{1- \alpha}
&\Leftrightarrow&&
w_1 &= \lambda \alpha x_1^{\alpha -1} x_2^{1- \alpha}
\\[\medskipamount]
\frac{\partial f_A (x)}{\partial x_2} & = w_2 - \lambda x_1^\alpha (1-
\alpha) x_2^{- \alpha}
&\Leftrightarrow&&
w_2 &= \lambda x_1^\alpha (1-\alpha)x_2^{-\alpha}
\\[\medskipamount]
\frac{\partial f_A (x)}{\partial \lambda} & =x_1^\alpha x_2^{1-\alpha} - y
&\Leftrightarrow&&
y &= x_1^\alpha x_2^{1-\alpha}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result align]

Smaller spacing can be achieved by using `alignat` instead of `align`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{3}
\frac{\partial f_A (x)}{\partial x_1} & = w_1 - \lambda \alpha x_1^{\alpha
-1} x_2^{1- \alpha}
&\quad\Leftrightarrow&\quad&
w_1 &= \lambda \alpha x_1^{\alpha -1} x_2^{1- \alpha}
\\[\medskipamount]
\frac{\partial f_A (x)}{\partial x_2} & = w_2 - \lambda x_1^\alpha (1-
\alpha) x_2^{- \alpha}
&\Leftrightarrow&&
w_2 &= \lambda x_1^\alpha (1-\alpha)x_2^{-\alpha}
\\[\medskipamount]
\frac{\partial f_A (x)}{\partial \lambda} & =x_1^\alpha x_2^{1-\alpha} - y
&\Leftrightarrow&&
y &= x_1^\alpha x_2^{1-\alpha}
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result alignat]

Comment: I wouldn't use `em` units.

Comment: @egreg The `0.7em` comes from the question. I have now changed it to `\medskipamount`, its quite  close to `0.7em` (6 pt vs. 7 pt). Depending on the available space, also `\smallskipamount` is quite enough (3 pt). The `\...skipamount` specifications also have some shrink and stretch components, making it easier for TeX to break pages.